# Scrape Google books ngrams with RCurl and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, n-gram

I'm finding it easy enough to scrape Google books ngrams with RCurl. For the URL "https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfoo%3B%2Cc0" I'm just using regex to extract the data after "var data = [{"timeseries":". But when trying to scrape the node I get nowhere. I can see a node "td.line-content" so the code below should work, but it doesn't

```
html_node(read_html("https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfoo%3B%2Cc0"),"td.line-content")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which part you want to scrape? I couldn't fine anything similar to `var data = [{"timeseries":". ` in the page nor the class "td.line-content"

Comment: The data used in the graph . .  it's the numbers following var data in the raw HTML

Comment: I guess you'll still need some regex to parse the data. This is closer `url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('script') %>%
  .[[9]] %>%
  html_text()`

Comment: I still roll with old-school syntax, so yes, `html_text(html_nodes(read_html(url),'script')[[9]])` does the trick. Thanks for confirming that there's no pure node scrape here, but CSS plus some regex clean-up. Should I answer my own question?

Comment: Sure, please do.

Comment: https://ngrams.dev provides a REST API where you can fetch this data as JSON.